# Manual Transmission Oil Potentially Low

Tags: nissan, manual-transmission, transmission-fluid, almera

So I changed my drive/axle shaft and even though I had the car tipped/jacked on one side. Quite a bit of transmission oil still leaked out. If I was to estimate maybe 0.4L (400ml)?

To add to my problems, the filler nut would not open, probably rusted up no clue, took it to a shop and even they couldn't open it. So will take it to another one tomorrow.

If I can't get the filler hole open. What sort of damage is possible?

I'm not going to even bother thinking about getting a new transmission box changed for this 2006 car not worth it.

To add, previously I had a lot of gear grinding when shifting, so far I haven't experienced any of that as yet. Not sure whether that's a good or bad sign.

Comment: What is the make/model of the vehicle in question?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Nissan Almera N16 2006 1.5 Petrol Manual.

Answer (score 0):

Your gearbox holds three liters, so you've lost about 15%.  That much loss will not cause significant harm.  It will, however, increase operating temperature which will accelerate wear over the long term.

Spray the stuck drain plug with a 50-50 mixture of automatic transmission fluid and acetone.  Apply some heat with a torch, if possible, then re-coat and allow to sit overnight.  Tap the bolt lightly with a hammer for a minute now and then.  When you attempt to loosen it, start by rocking the wrench back-and-forth in a tighten/loosen motion.  Finally, have your mechanic use an impact wrench.

Comment: I took my car to another shop today and upon closer inspection the filler nut is internally rounded off. He did mention that I could fill it through the top breather hole although it will take some time. Prior to losing the oil, my shifts felt rough and sometimes caused slight grinding. I haven't experienced that ever since losing the oil. I'm wondering whether it was overfilled (by whoever must have been few years now)? Thinking this as if the drive/axle shaft hole is similar level to filler hole, and I had the car slanted against it, yet oil was lost, wouldn't that indicate overfill?

Comment: To add, I am wondering whether to fill in the full 0.4L lost, fill in only 0.2L (half of it) or to run the car and see if anything worsens. Based on my previous reply.

Comment: Your reasoning sounds correct to me.  I would just leave it alone at this point.